# Changing Max Duration of Video while Recording iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-capture, avcapturesession

I am initially starting recording with a specified Maximum Time Threshold.

```
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput* output;
//initialisations, other configurations...

//Here i am setting up my MaxDuration before starting recording.
[output setMaxRecordedDuration:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(MY_MAX_LENGTH, 600)];

//Starting recording here
[output startRecordingToOutputFileURL:MY_FILE_URL recordingDelegate:self];
```

I need to change the Maximum Recording Time Threshold while recording is going on.

What i have tried so far:

```
[output setMaxRecordedDuration:kCMTimeInvalid];
```

I am calling the above line of code while recording is going on, but the recording stops at the previous `MY_MAX_LENGTH` time mark and then after the recording is restarted the new Maximum duration `kCMTimeInvalid` is set on the `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` Object.

Am i doing anything wrong here? Please point me into right direction. 
Any Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to set a MAX_LENGHT at first and then override it with `kCMTimeInvalid` while recording? It seems like you will change it always, no matter what, right? So, instantiate the object with `kCMTimeInvalid` instead of a MAX_LENGHT.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am maintaining a flow where i am saving Video in Fragments. I am not changing the Time to `kCMTimeInvalid` always, there are few scenarios in my App when i have to change the duration to infinite Time and break the Video Fragmentation Logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For achieving this, i used manual `start-recording/stop-recording` technique (instead of Maximmum Time logic) using a timer and some flags.

I hope this helps anyone who is into the similar problem.